# How do I update a variable within jQuery on hover?

Tags: jquery, variables, animation, gsap

Just wondering how I can dry up this code I'm working on for a navigation bar.
I am animating the strokeDashoffset using tweenlite (GSAP), every time the user hovers over a particular element, the stroke changes.

Ideally I would like to have one tweenlite at the bottom of the function and pass the stroke variable in so it changes.
However, the stroke variable is only set once and doesnt change.

I have commented out the tweenlites that do actually work, but ovbiously its not the most ideal solution.

```
    function navHover() {

    var stroke = 2300;
    $("#nav_home").hover(function() {
        stroke = 2300;
    });
    $("#nav_about").hover(function() {
        stroke = 2100;
        //TweenLite.to('#navline', 0.5, {strokeDashoffset: 2100});
        //TweenLite.to('#left3d', 0.5, {x: 200, transformOrigin:"0% 100%"});
    });
    $("#nav_skills").hover(function() {
        stroke = 1900;
        //TweenLite.to('#navline', 0.5, {strokeDashoffset: 1900});
        //TweenLite.to('#left3d', 0.5, {x: 400, transformOrigin:"0% 100%"});
    });
    $("#nav_contact").hover(function() {
        stroke = 1700;
        //TweenLite.to('#navline', 0.5, {strokeDashoffset: 1700});
        //TweenLite.to('#left3d', 0.5, {x: 600, transformOrigin:"0% 100%"});
    });

    console.log(stroke);
    TweenLite.to('#navline', 0.5, {strokeDashoffset: stroke});
    TweenLite.to('#left3d', 0.5, {x: 0, transformOrigin:"0% 100%"});
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just put the two `TweenLite.to(...)` statements (or just the first one, actually, since the other one doesn't use `stroke`) into a function and call it whenever `stroke` changes, passing it as a parameter?

Comment: How are you using `navHover()` function? Are you calling it once when your page loads or did you bind it to the `hover` event on a `nav`?

Comment: @Jeto - Would you mind showing me? I cant understand what you mean, apologies.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Im using it once when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Not being DRY might not be the biggest problem with your code. But, let's start with it.

DRY means don't repeat yourself. Which, at a simple level, translates into: whenever I need to run the same code again, rather than placing it where I need it, I'll make a function and call that function from each place where I want to run it.
At its core, this is a simple matter of running the same code but writing less characters.

Sometimes, you want to run the same code with slightly different values. That's when you use parameters. (Which is your case).

Other times, you want to change things to other elements based on the element that initiated the call to the function. That's when you use `this` (a gross simplification, but, in principle, correct).

Your code would look like this, without repeating yourself:

```js
function tweenTo(offset=2300, x=0) {
  TweenLite.to('#navline', 0.5, {strokeDashoffset: offset});
  TweenLite.to('#left3d', 0.5, {x: x, transformOrigin:"0% 100%"});
}

function navHover() {

    $("#nav_home").hover(function() { tweenTo() });
    $("#nav_about").hover(function() { tweenTo(2100, 200) });
    $("#nav_skills").hover(function() { tweenTo(1900, 400) });
    $("#nav_contact").hover(function() { tweenTo(1700, 600) });

    tweenTo();
}
```

I do hope all is clear so far.

---

Now, if you're calling this function only once, when your page has loaded, it's probably all good and what you want to happen. You basically run

```
tweenTo(); // which means tweenTo(2300,0);
```

when the page has loaded and also bind running `tweenTo()`s to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on some elements in your page, with specific values for each case.

---

let's take a quick look at what [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) actually does. It is a shorthand method.

As in: it's a shorter form to write a longer function for a commonly used scenario.
It's a short form for

```
.mouseenter(function(){
  /* code run on mouseenter event */ 
}).mouseleave(function(){
  /* code run on mouseleave event */
})`
```

This function is designed to make two bindings:

- one to `mouseenter` (first param)
- and one to `mouseleave` (second param - defaults to first param).

If you don't give it two functions, it will automatically assume you want the same function bound on both events. Which means the `tweenTo()` is run when mouse pointer enters the element **and** when it leaves the element, which might not be what you want to happen.

If you only want the function run when mouse enters, bind to `mouseenter`. Especially if your elements are adjacent and when mouse enters one, it also leaves another, because it means you're running tween animations at the same time and it might not be what you want to happen.

---

My third point would have been if you ran this function on `hover` event of another element, as that would have been really bad, potentially crashing your page. But, since you told me it's not the case, I won't go there in detail.